# match pattern between symbols, after given pattern

Tags: python, regex, search, pattern-matching

I would like to find the first occurrence of a string, after a certain other string, and between a certain pattern. The documents that I am parsing are not xml, but have similar rules of start/end. and example of what I would be looking at:

```
...b.filext", "{xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx}"
```

and I am trying to get the string between { and }, right after an occurrence of a vcxproj, every time it happens in the document.
I tried the following, but I get a list of None:

```
my_list=[]
for line in text.split('.vcxproj'):
    if '{' in line: 
        my_list.append(re.match( r"(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\})", line))
```

I have tried to alter my expression but no success. Help ? Thank you.

Comment: Note that if the syntax isn't recursive (the text to match can also occur as a substring), it's not like XML. It's this recursive nature that makes regexes unsuitable for XML parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
    re.findall(r"vcxproj.*?\{(.*?)\}", text)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`re.match`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match) matches only at the beginning of the string. Try `re.search`. Alternatively, replace the loop with [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall).

Comment: Thank you, I am getting matches. But they look like: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x023AE220> instead of the actual string... I didn't expect that ?

Comment: @user1217150: `re.search` returns a `match` object. In order to access the matched string, you must call `.group()` or `.groups()` on the match object.

Comment: @user1217150: read over the [re documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). So far, all your questions are answered there. Consider picking a [meaningful username](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), so you'll receive notifications of [@replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/133817).

Comment: ... Your question about match objects is skirting the edge of being a new question. Outside of asking for clarification, comments shouldn't be used to ask additional questions. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. If you have questions beyond what you originally asked, first check whether the question has already been asked, and post a new question if not.

Comment: ...  If you have additional requirements that aren't yet described in the question, edit the question rather than posting a comment.